# Magento 2.4.3 Object not found on new installation

Tags: magento2, installation

I have copied magento 2 git repo in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/magento2

On visiting http://localhost/magento2/ it shows - Object not found!

On http://localhost/magento2/pub it does show
Vendor autoload is not found. Please run 'composer install' under application root directory.

How to make it work with " http://localhost/magento2/ " in mac ?

Comment: any thoughts on this ?

Comment: any thoughts on this ?

Answer (score 0):

Simple response : You can't

> Operating systems (Linux x86-64)
> Linux distributions, such as RedHat Enterprise Linux (RHEL), CentOS, Ubuntu, Debian, and similar. Magento is not supported on Microsoft Windows and macOS.

You need to run it under a virtual linux machine or use a docker environment that will emulate linux.